# Sitemap is HTML - but it's supposed to be XML

Tags: cakephp, google-search-console

I have a small web application made with cakephp, and I am trying to submit its `sitemap.xml` to Google Webmaster Tools. This is the sitemap's address: http://gomme.gommarolo.org/sitemap.xml

The problem is, when I submit that address, google tells me that the sitemap is in HTML format, thus suggesting me to use another format.

The content of that page, itself, looks like a proper XML file and even chrome says that its content type is application/xml.

What's wrong with that sitemap?

Comment: logout from your app and try to access sitemap ;)

Comment: Your URL leads to a login page, which definitely looks like HTML to me.

Comment: D'oh! Thanks guys...